# Azure Data Factory : How to access these metrics for each activity run shown under "Activity Metric Image" in the Azure Portal?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-factory

[Activity Metrics Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vywg7.png) I have Azure data factory slices which are scheduled to run on every week. I have more than 500 slices.

I need power-shell command to know how many records are inserted by each slice and duration.

My use case :  I want maintain the audit that how much records are getting inserted by every slice on every week.

Below is the code snippet which gives me list of sliece and there run status. I want to know the total number rows inserted by each slice and I dont find any attribute for that. Please suggest

```js
$tableName=@() 

$tableNames=@()

#$Subscription="Provide Subscription ID"  
  
#Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId  $Subscription    

$DataFactoryName="Data factory name comes here" 
$resourceGroupName ="Resource group name comes here" 
  
$startDateTime ="2018-01-07" #Start Date for Slices 
$endDateTime="2018-01-14" # End Date for Slices

#Get Dataset names in Data Factory – you can explicitly give a table name using $tableName variable if you like to run only for an individual tablename 
$tableNames = Get-AzureRMDataFactoryDataset -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName | ForEach {$_.DatasetName}

#$tableNames #lists tablenames

foreach ($tableName in $tableNames) 
{ 
    $temp_slice_name = Get-AzureRMDataFactorySlice -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -DatasetName $tableName -StartDateTime $startDateTime -EndDateTime $endDateTime -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ErrorAction Stop 
 $slices +=$temp_slice_name
 $temp_slice_name
 @($slices).Count
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you upload what you already have?

Comment: Added code snippet in the post. Please suggest